# HTTP status to return when POST is called multiple times?

Tags: rest, post, http-post

I have a POST end-point which creates/inserts a new record in database.

**POST**    /payments/cards will add/save a payment card in DB and return the added card information in response when 200 OK. Now, if we invoke the same end-point again, its updating the existing payment card in DB which shouldn't happen.

So, I am adding logic check if the payment card already exists so that we don't update it.

What is the HTTP status to be returned in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

For a POST response, use 201 if a new record is created, otherwise use 200 or maybe 409 instead.I think that it is 409 Conflict which is the most appropriate, however, seldom seen in the wild of course:

> The request could not be completed due to a conflict with the current state of the resource. This code is only allowed in situations where it is expected that the user might be able to resolve the conflict and resubmit the request. The response body SHOULD include enough information for the user to recognize the source of the conflict. Ideally, the response entity would include enough information for the user or user agent to fix the problem; however, that might not be possible and is not required.
>
> Conflicts are most likely to occur in response to a PUT request. For example, if versioning were being used and the entity being PUT included changes to a resource which conflict with those made by an earlier (third-party) request, the server might use the 409 response to indicate that it can't complete the request. In this case, the response entity would likely contain a list of the differences between the two versions in a format defined by the response Content-Type.

Comment: Yeah, I considered 409. Is 422 more appropriate? Any thoughts please.. 422 UNPROCESSABLE ENTITY
The server understands the content type of the request entity (hence a 415 Unsupported Media Type status code is inappropriate), and the syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a 400 Bad Request status code is inappropriate) but was unable to process the contained instructions.

For example, this error condition may occur if an XML request body contains well-formed (i.e., syntactically correct), but semantically erroneous, XML instructions.

Comment: Definitely woudl also suggest 409, or simply 403.